# calendar keeps showing the wrong time

Tags: javascript, django, timezone, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am trying to fix the timezones for the calendar. It sends to the django server the times as an ISO format with the offsets as the timezone that the user selects at the dropdown menu and saves it. It is saved in the server correctly. But upon loading it into the calendar, it seems to interpret it as actually 5 hours ahead (America/Chicago CST time) instead of the time format as 00:00:00 that was input originally. And yes the offset is -5.

I've already tried removing the timeZone option in the fullcalendar variable and that didn't do anything.

```
#calendar.html

var calendar = $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
          // timeZone: $("#id_timezone").val(),
          timeZone: "UTC", #UTC is just for testing purposes
          header: {
            left: "prev,next today",
            center: "title",
            right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay",
          },
          events: "/all_events",
          selectable: true,
          selectHelper: true,
          editable: true,
          eventLimit: true,
          eventDurationEditable: true,

          select: function (start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt("Enter Event Title");
            if (title) {
              var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
              var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
              $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/add_event",
                data: {
                  title: title,
                  start: start,
                  end: end,
                  timezone: $("#id_timezone").val(),
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                  calendar.fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
                  alert("Added Successfully " + start);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                  alert(
                    "There is a problem!!! " + start + $("#timezone").val()
                  );
                },
              });
            }
          },
          eventResize: function (event) {
            var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(
              event.start,
              "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
            );
            var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
            var title = event.title;
            var id = event.id;
            $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "/update",
              data: {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end,
                id: id,
                timezone: $("#id_timezone").val(),
              },
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (data) {
                calendar.fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
                alert("Event Update");
              },
              error: function (data) {
                alert("There is a problem!!!");
              },
            });
          },

          eventDrop: function (event) {
            var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(
              event.start,
              "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
            );
            var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
            var title = event.title;
            var id = event.id;
            $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "/update",
              data: {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end,
                id: id,
                timezone: $("#id_timezone").val(),
              },
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (data) {
                calendar.fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
                alert("Event Update");
              },
              error: function (data) {
                alert("There is a problem!!!");
              },
            });
          },

          eventClick: function (event) {
            $("#eventModal").modal("show");
            $("#modalTitle").val(event.title);
            const dayStart = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD");
            const dayEnd = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD");
            var timeStart = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "HH:mm:ss");
            var timeEnd = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "HH:mm:ss");
            $("#dayStart").val(dayStart);
            $("#dayEnd").val(dayEnd);
            $("timeStart").val(timeStart);
            $("timeEnd").val(timeEnd);
            $("#desc").val(event.desc);
            $("#saveEvent").on("click", function () {
              var id = event.id;
              $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/updateEvent",
                data: {
                  id: id,
                  title: $("#modalTitle").val(),
                  dayStart: $("#dayStart").val(),
                  dayEnd: $("#dayEnd").val(),
                  timeStart: $("#timeStart").val(),
                  timeEnd: $("#timeEnd").val(),
                  desc: $("#desc").val(),
                  timezone: $("#id_timezone").val(),
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (id) {
                  calendar.fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
                  alert("Event Updated");
                },
                error: function (data) {
                  alert("There is a problem!!! " + id);
                },
              });
            });

            $("#removeBtn").on("click", function () {
              var id = event.id;
              $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/remove",
                data: { id: id },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                  calendar.fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
                  alert("Event Removed");
                },
                error: function (data) {
                  alert("There is a problem!!!");
                },
              });
            });
          },
        });
```

```
#views.py

def all_events(request):
    user = request.user.id                                                                                                 
    user_events = Events.objects.filter(user=user)   
    program_events = Events.objects.filter(user__isnull=True)                                                                                 
    out = []                 
    tz = afbUsers.objects.get(pk=user)
    timezone = pytz.timezone(tz.timezone)                                                                                            
    for event in user_events:    
        # start = event.start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        # print(start)
        # start = parser.parse(start)
        # start =  start.astimezone(timezone) 
        # print(start)
        # end = event.end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        # end = parser.parse(end)
        # end =  end.astimezone(timezone)                                                                                 
        out.append({                                                                                                     
            'title': event.name,                                                                                         
            'id': event.id,                                                                                              
            'start': event.start.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"),                                                         
            'end': event.end.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"),                                                             
        })          
    # for event in program_events:  
    #     start = event.start 
    #     start =  start.astimezone(utc_timezone)  
    #     end = event.end
    #     end =  end.astimezone(utc_timezone)                                                                                           
    #     out.append({                                                                                                     
    #         'title': event.name,                                                                                         
    #         'id': event.id,                                                                                              
    #         'start': start.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"),                                                         
    #         'end': end.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"),                                                             
    #     })                                                                                                         

                                                                       
    return JsonResponse(out, safe=False)
```

EDIT: I am providing specific worked data examples.

```
// data example

{
  "id": 1,
  "user": 42, // This should be the ID of an existing user in the afbUsers table
  "name": "Community Meetup",
  "start": "2024-04-26T18:00:00Z",
  "end": "2024-04-26T20:00:00Z",
  "desc": "A gathering for the local community to discuss upcoming projects and initiatives."
}
```

Comment: please kindly share what javsacript library you use for this javascript so everyone can understand how the library works and can help you

Comment: @BilhasryRamadhony the question is already tagged with [tag:fullcalendar], which answers your question. Based on the code syntax, it looks like the (fairly old) version 3 of that library.

Comment: Please provide specific, worked data examples so we can understand the exact nature of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I just edited my post to include a data example.

Comment: @HokoA based on the documentation here, if you use UTC, you can use UTC function instead https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-object. Hope it helps

Comment: @BilhasryRamadhony OP is using an old version of fullCalendar (v3) so that information doesn't apply. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/date-library is the applicable date documentation for v3

Comment: @HokoA As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/timezone if you don't specify a timezone option then any dates parsed will use the timezone offset specified in the date string. Your example data `"2024-04-26T18:00:00Z"` shows that the server is supplying the date in UTC format (that's what the `Z` means), so fullCalendar will show it in that timezone.

Comment: So I updated the calendar to v6 but now I am coming up with more errors while retrieving all events to display as well as add events. The events don't show in the calendar even though they are in the server.

Comment: It's a bad time to do a major upgrade when you're in the middle of fixing a bug like this tbh, but ok. Anyway to get any help with your new problems you'll need to [edit] your question to show us your latest code and tell us what error messages you are seeing. We cannot guess what the problem is just from a very short description. Thanks

Comment: Well I figured it out. Updating the code to the newest version worked. I needed to use the correct CDN version and initialize the calendar correctly. Thanks!

Comment: And now the timezone issue is resolved too?

Comment: Yes timezone issue is resolved too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by initializing the calendar correctly according to the version of the CDN I was using. I corrected to the latest version 6.

```
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.11/index.global.min.js'></script>

var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  });
  calendar.render();
```